# Theorem, Inverse of Matrix is the Sum of Power

Tags: linear-algebra

I noticed that $(1+S)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}S^n$, where S is a square matrix. Is there any theorem related this identity?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $(I - S)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty S^n$.  There are cases where the right hand side fails to converge, so it holds only conditionally.  But it is a pretty important idea, cropping up in lots of contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only true (i.e., converges), if each eigenvalue of $S$ has absolute value less than $1$. Is has been discussed often on MSE, e.g.,[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989960/inverse-matrices-and-infinite-series), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604820/a-problem-with-the-geometric-series-and-matrices?rq=1). If $S$ is nilpotent with $S^n=0$, then
$$
(1+S)^{-1}=I-S+S^2\cdots \pm S^{n-1}.
$$