# Writing $B^{-1}$ in terms of $I, B, B^2$.

Tags: matrices, inverse

> Give an expression for an inverse of a matrix, i.e., $B^{-1}$, using only $I, B, B^2$.

This seems like it shouldn't be too difficult but I am unable to find anything close.

Comment: Do you mean the inverse of $B^{-1}$? That's clearly $B$.

Comment: No, I am asking for $B^{-1}=...$, not $(B^{-1})^{-1}=...$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773263/theorem-inverse-of-matrix-is-the-sum-of-power?noredirect=1&lq=1). If $B^3=0$ we only need $I,B,B^2$. But your question is not clear.

Comment: If the matrix is $3\times3$, then, given the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we have that $B$ satisfy its own characteristic equation $B^3 + a_1 B^2 + a_2 B + a_3 I = 0$, so that $B^3$ can be expressed in terms of $B^2, B, I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to express $M^{-1}$ by a *linear combination* of $I_n$, $M$ and $M^2$, this work if $n\leq 3$ using Cayley–Hamilton theorem. But its not possible if $n\geq 4$. Take $$M=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
1&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Then 
$$M^2=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
1&2&1&0\\
0&1&2&1\\
0&0&1&2\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{array}\right)$$

So $Vect(I_4,M,M^2)\subset\{A\in M_4(\Bbb{R})~|~A_{1,4}=0\}$.

But 
$$M^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
1&-1&1&-1\\
0&1&-1&1\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{array}\right)$$

So $M^{-1}$ is not a linear combination of $I_4,M$ and $M^2$.